# Using UIAccessibilityAction:accessibilityPerformEscape

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

Apple's docs for this protocol says of accessibilityPerformEscape

"Implement this method on an element or containing view that can be revealed modally or in a hierarchy. When a VoiceOver user performs a dismiss action, this method dismisses the view. For example, you might implement this method for a popover in order to give users a deliberate dismiss action to perform that closes the popover."

I can't find any information on what the dismiss action is.  Anybody have any clues?

Answer (score 5):

Never mind, just found it here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Accessibility/AccessibilityfromtheViewControllersPerspective.html

It's a two-fingered Z shape.

Comment: You should accept your question (even if it's your own answer) to indicate to other people that it answered.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Link is no longer available.